# Cannot see website gcloud SSL certificate issue

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, gcloud, web-hosting

I have been following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) to host a static website in Google Cloud.

I tried to follow it as close as I can. I've set up my bucket which I can reliably connect to using the  I set up my domain and A records in gcloud DNS. When I type this command to 'describe' my target proxy...

```sh
gcloud compute target-https-proxies describe vincent-cinardo-lb-target-proxy
```

I get the following message in each link:

> "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

So I tried going to the link and it recommends I use *"Google Identity Services"*. It's confusing since it's not in the tutorial, but I did as it said, added my domains to the Authorized Javascript origins

[image]

I configured my consent and included the client library in each header in every one of html files:

```html
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

I am still getting the same message about OAuth 2.0 access tokens as before. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Did you run one of the commands first **gcloud auth login** or **gcloud auth application-default login**?

Comment: No but I just did now.  In the gcloud shell I get back this when I run the second command: 
https://gyazo.com/c9a87abfd925cc2c7d4ef854b943ea4c

When I run it I get error: ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.login) Cannot launch browser. Please run this command on a machine where gcloud can launch a web browser.

Do I need to run this command in Linux? My computer is dual-booted so I could.

Comment: The Google Cloud CLI supports Windows/Linux and Mac. I recommend reading the documentation on how to install and set up your environment for Google Cloud. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing

Comment: Okay I successfully ran that/authorized

Comment: Now that you have authenticated/authorized the CLI, edit your question to show your current problem.

Comment: It didn't change. Could it be becuase I don't have <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"> in my headers too? Gonna try that.

Comment: Still the same error, not really sure what to do

Comment: Are you running the command from [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell) or from the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb)? If you run the command `gcloud compute target-https-proxies list` does it retrieve the list of your _Google Compute Engine target HTTPS proxies_ or does it show the same error as before? Are you the owner of the project or is it a shared one?